# Access user creating a record in before insert trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class, null-pointer, before-trigger

I'm trying to set some default values for contact fields based on which user is inserting the record into the database, but am coming up against a NullPointerException as the CreatedById is null before insert. Is there any other way I can evaluate the user creating the record before it is inserted into the database?

Here is my trigger:

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert,before update, after insert, after update, before delete, after delete) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleBeforeUpdate(Trigger.old,Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate(Trigger.old,Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isBefore){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleBeforeDelete(Trigger.old,Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isDelete && Trigger.isAfter){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleAfterDelete(Trigger.old,Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else if(Trigger.isUndelete && Trigger.isBefore){
            ContactTriggerHandler.handleBeforeUndelete(Trigger.old,Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        else{}
    }
```

and my simplified handler class:

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {

        public static void handleBeforeInsert(List<Contact> newContacts) {
            setDefaultValues(newContacts);
            }

        private static void setDefaultValues(List<Contact> newContacts){
            Set<ID> userIds = new Set<ID>(); //Define empty set of user ids to use in SOQL query below        
            for(Contact con : newContacts){ //Loop through contacts to populate set of user ids
                userIds.add(con.CreatedById); //add user id of user who created the record
            }
            Map<ID, User> userMap = new Map<ID,User>([Select ID,UserRole.Name from User Where Id IN :userIds]);
            //Query for, and generate a map to get the role of the user who created the record
            for(Contact con : newContacts){
                if(userMap.get(con.CreatedById).UserRole.Name.contains('Sales')){
                //My logic here based on the role of the user creating the contact
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that CreatedById is null until the record is inserted into the database. Is there any other way I can evaluate the user inserting the record without having to do this in an after insert context? I have other logic that fires to create custom child objects after insert that are dependent upon the values I want to set with my before insert trigger.

I'm fairly new to apex and programming in general, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A call to `System.UserInfo.getUserId()` will give you the ID of the currently executing user during any transaction. This should solve your problem because the CreatedById always receives this value once it gets inserted.